# How to get VKontakte photo, name, id using PHP with JSON

Tags: php, json, vk

I have the issuses with VK access_token. I added to `&access_token=` a **Secure key** of the project, but VKontakte still says that `User authorization failed: invalid access_token (4).`.

How I can fix it?

```
$url = 'personasvk';

function get_vk($username) {
  $get = get_data('https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?user_id='.$username.'&v=5.85&access_token=SECURE_KEY_OF_PROJECT');
  $result = json_decode($get, true);

  if (empty($result['response'][0]['gid']) || empty($result['response'][0]['screen_name'])) {
    return false;
  } else {
    return $result;
  }
}
$vk_data = get_vk($url);
$title = $vk_data['response'][0]['screen_name'];
$link_id = $vk_data['response'][0]['gid'];
$image = $vk_data['response'][0]['photo'];

echo $title;
```

Comment: is it working your browser when you just hit the url with `access_token`?

Comment: @smart-googler What do you mean?

Comment: I mean is it works when you try your url to get data from the api on your browser without the code?

Comment: @smart-googler No. The problem is with `access_token`, I've tried different methods but I still don't know why it saying that `access_token` is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding it in the body of your POST request.

I am not familiar with PHP, but this curl gives me all the necessary information.

```
    curl -X POST \
        -d 'v=5.85' \
        -d 'access_token=SECURE_KEY_OF_PROJECT' \
        -d 'user_id=700' \
        https://api.vk.com/method/users.get
```